# SQL Delete low counts

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with this data:

```
Id     Qty  
--     ---  
A       1  
A       2  
A       3  
B       112  
B       125  
B       109
```

But I'm supposed to only have the max values for each id. Max value for A is 3 and for B is 125. How can I isolate (and delete) the other values?

The final table should look like this :

```
Id     Qty  
--     ---   
A       3  
B       125
```

Running MySQL 4.1

Comment: Do you have a real ID field, which is unique to each row?

Comment: You really should have one... Only n-m tables should exist without one

Comment: I know. But I didn't design the tables.

Comment: @Heiko: Yes every table should have a primary key, but it's immaterial to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh wait. Got a simpler solution :
I'll select all the max values(group by id), export the data, flush the table, reimport only the max values.

```
CREATE TABLE tabletemp LIKE table;  
INSERT INTO tabletemp SELECT id,MAX(qty) FROM table GROUP BY id;  
DROP TABLE table;
RENAME TABLE tabletemp TO table;
```

Thanks to all !

Comment: You could create a new table, select the values into it, delete the original table & finally rename the new table to use the name of the old table.

Comment: Will accept my own answer in 2 days unless someone come up with a real "non-cheating" way of doing it. With a join and stuff... just wondering which is faster at runtime.

Comment: In theory, you ought to be able to do something like `DELETE FROM tbl WHERE qty < (SELECT MAX(t.qty) FROM tbl t WHERE t.Id = tbl.Id)` but MySQL has a restriction where you can't have the table you're updating or deleting from in a subquery, you get error 1093. Your solution is probably the best.

Comment: For what it's worth, doing a `truncate table mytbl;` will be lots faster, since you're not wrapping that delete in a transaction (as `delete from` does). In other comments, you said you had a fairly small table (~400k rows), so a `delete` will happen pretty quickly, anyway.

Comment: You can speed it up by renaming the temporary table instead of copying everything a second time: DROP TABLE `table`; RENAME TABLE `tabletemp` TO `table`;

Answer (score 1):

Try this in SQL Server:

```
delete from tbl o
left outer join 
(Select max(qty) anz , id
from tbl i
group by i.id) k on o.id = k.id and k.anz = o.qty
where k.id is null
```

Revision 2 for MySQL... Can anyone check this one?:

```
delete from tbl o
where concat(id,qty) not in 
    (select concat(id,anz) from (Select max(qty) anz , id
    from tbl i
    group by i.id))
```

Explanation:

Since I was supposed to not use joins (See comments about MySQL Support on joins and delete/update/insert), I moved the subquery into a IN(a,b,c) clause.

Inside an In clause I can use a subquery, but that query is only allowed to return one field. So in order to filter all elements that are not the maximum, i need to concat both fields into a single one, so i can return it inside the in clause. So basically my query inside the IN returns the biggest ID+QTY only. To compare it with the main table i also need to make a concat on the outside, so the data for both fields match.

Basically the In clause contains:
("A3","B125")

Disclaimer: The above query is "evil!" since it uses a function (concat) on fields to compare against. This will cause any index on those fields to become almost useless. You should never formulate a query that way that is run on a regular basis. I only wanted to try to bend it so it works on mysql.

Example of this "bad construct":
(Get all o from the last 2 weeks)
select ... from orders where orderday + 14 > now()

You should allways do:
select ... from orders where orderday  > now() - 14

The difference is subtle: Version 2 only has to do the math once, and is able to use the index, and version 1 has to do the math for every single row in the orders table., and you can forget about the index usage...

Comment: Unknown column 'o.anz' in 'on clause'. You anz is scoped inside the ().

Comment: I also took out the outer join because its not recognised in mysql... not sure how to adapt it : right outer join or left outer join.

Comment: love how someone upvoted this and it doesn't even work (for now)

Comment: Sorry... only know T-SQL... Thats why I added the disclaimer there. But thats the basic construct i would use.

Comment: being able to use joins in INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements is SQL Server-specific

Comment: Don't be sorry. I'm really thankfull you tried. You obviously know your way around sql and after thinking about it I think it's great you've been rewarded for it.

Comment: Can you explain to me the goal of the Concat ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this:

```
delete from T
where exists (
  select * from T as T2
  where T2.Id = T.Id
  and T2.Qty > T.Qty
);
```

For those who might have similar question in the future, this might be supported some day (it is now in SQL Server 2005 and later)

It won't require a join, and it has advantages over the use of a temporary table if the table has dependencies

```
with Tranked(Id,Qty,rk) as (
  select
    Id, Qty,
    rank() over (
      partition by Id
      order by Qty desc
    )
  from T
)
  delete from Tranked
  where rk > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to go via another table (among other things that makes a single delete statement here quite impossible in mysql is you can't delete from a table and use the same table in a subquery).

```
BEGIN;
create temporary table tmp_del select id,max(qty) as qty from the_tbl;
delete the_tbl from the_tbl,tmp_del where 
  the_tbl.id=tmp_del.id and the_tbl.qty=tmp_del.qty;
drop table tmp_del;
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

MySQL 4.0 and later supports a simple multi-table syntax for [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/delete.html):

```
DELETE t1 FROM MyTable t1 JOIN MyTable t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.qty < t2.qty;
```

This produces a join of each row with a given id to all other rows with the same id, and deletes only the row with the lesser `qty` in each pairing.  After this is all done, the row with the greatest `qty` per group of `id` is left not deleted.

If you only have one row with a given id, it still works because a single row is naturally the one with the greatest value.

---

FWIW, I just tried my solution using MySQL 5.0.75 on a Macbook Pro 2.40GHz.  I inserted 1 million rows of synthetic data, with different numbers of rows per "group":

- 2 rows per `id` completes in 26.78 sec.
- 5 rows per `id` completes in 43.18 sec.
- 10 rows per `id` completes in 1 min 3.77 sec.
- 100 rows per `id` completes in 6 min 46.60 sec.
- 1000 rows per `id` didn't complete before I terminated it.

Comment: I will test this but a full join like this cost A LOT. Pretty sure it will be really really long.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this solution is O(n). And I'm working with a very huge table.

Comment: Query stopped after an hour or so because it still wasn't done. Sorry but as I thought, a full join is impractical on a large table : the table has 376 000 entries. My solution only took a few seconds.

Comment: @Silence: 376,000 rows is *not* a large table. The issue is how many rows get returned back on this query. In this case, it's a direct correlation between number of rows per ID and those rows returned.  You can get into the case of a near Cartesian join if you have very few IDs in those 376,000 rows. Moreover, please do not use big-O notation when discussing database operations. Most of the operations are done relationally and are not imperative, like big-O describes. The reason that this approach is slow is due to you having a low number of valid IDs, not the size of the table.

Comment: Sorry. Fairly new at SQL. Thanks for the precisions Eric.